# is there anyway to save the response my php script will produce into a variable?

Tags: php

i am building my own API monitoring tool and i want to know if it's possible to save the response that the PHP script wanted to be monitored will generate to a variable to use it in other stuff after script code process complete, something similar to `ob_start();` in the top of the script then

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

in the bottom and then do what i want with $output

is this the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out if i use `ob_get_contents();` without requesting `ob_start();` it will show main output buffer value